# Banner Slider Magento Extension

Tags: magento2, banner-slider

I Need Magento 2 Banner extension slider, that will display image different for both mobile and desktop between the dates Which I saved.

Please suggest me for this?

Answer (score 0):

Among the various free extensions available, the one from Weltpixel stands out as an excellent choice that is well-suited to fulfill your requirements.

You can visit the official website at https://www.weltpixel.com/owl-carousel-and-slider.html to explore more about this extension, read user reviews, and get a deeper understanding of how it can enhance your website's visual appeal and functionality.